# Discover an image from under bright color bars

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, rgb

### Background

Given a black & white image covered with bright color bars, the goal is to identify it. The original image is still visible, though it isn't sharp enough to identify.

[image]

### Question

Given a pixel as `RGB` format, I need to identify if it's colored or black & white. Should I compare it to a range of values?

After identifying I would like to reverse the pixel to the original one `black & white`. What calculations should I do without overwriting the original pixel?

I've tried to zero values that might indicate colored pixels, but this technique overwrote the original image behind the color bars.

### Final Result

After reversing the original image should be visible enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try desaturating - by converting to HSV colourspace with `cvtColor(...BGR2HSV...)` and setting the saturation component to zero and then converting back to BGR colourspace.

Comment: You can experiment quickly in the Terminal with **ImageMagick** and achieve the above with `magick INPUT.JPG -modulate 100,0 OUTPUT.JPG`

Comment: How do these bright color bars appear/what do they result from? It appears as if the strips send one or more color channels to 255, leaving the others in tact, although it's hard to tell.

Comment: The color bars result from editing I guess, as part of a cyber challenge. From the color values I've extracted with open-cv, the colored pixels have indeed high values, usually 255, but it's hard to reverse the pixel to the overwritten black and white one.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `magick` performed well, it's a great workaround but doesn't have much to do with learning the pixels and processing the RGB values.

Comment: My very first comment above does exactly the same as the `magick` which was just a quick test of whether you liked it before writing the code suggested there.

Comment: @MarkSetchell alright! Seems like the best solution. If you would like to answer the quesiton in a way that other people can also take profit, I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out about your example image is that the color bands are very RGB-specific; the colors overlaid are pure red, green, blue, magenta, yellow, cyan, and white. This seems to suggest that the way that the image is modified is to send some random selection of the channels to 255 (or otherwise scale them up by some constant or multiplier). None of the bright spots in the image get darkened, which suggests that the values are only changed to higher values. The values are a little fuzzy as well, due to the image being a compressed jpeg.

To see this behavior a little more closely, we can take a look at the distribution of values in each color channel in the image over a specific column of the image. For example, the first column of the image has the following color distribution for the pixels:

[image: hist]

It's super obvious from this plot that the distribution of values on the red channel is completely different from the green and blue channels, and that all of the values are near the maximum for the red channel. This suggests a detection strategy of taking the median or mean of each channel over each column and threshold it to select the "bad" channels. For example, whatever channels have an average value over 230 or something for each column is a "bad" channel. Running through this process gives the following channels as bad; you can see that it maps pretty closely to the actual color bands in the image:

[image: thresh]

[image: orig]

You could also use statistical techniques, e.g. threshold the standard deviation instead of the actual values (or use some combination of values, standard deviation, skewness, kurtosis, etc) for some robustness.

We can impute the values in the bad channels with the mean or median of the rest of the channels:

[image: clean from std < thresh]

However, you can see there's some bright single-column strips throughout when you do this, which correspond to columns where the bad channel identification failed a bit. The failures happen partly because the image is a jpeg, partly because some of the colors blend together (i.e., the color changes don't necessarily happen right on the edge of a pixel), hard to select the right threshold, and so on. These issues are easier to see on an enlarged image:

[image: enlarged]

However, we can do something *much* simpler than all the above. In particular, for each column, we know that the bad channels are always the brightest channels. Since the image is grayscale ultimately, we only need one channel for every pixel. That means that we can simply pick the darkest channel for each column, and we'll never get a bad column (unless all three channels are bad, in which case the information is destroyed).

So the process is just to select the minimum over the color channels for each column, which is much more easily expressed in code than the above approaches. And we don't have to tune any thresholds, either.

```
# take the average value over each column
mean_columns = np.mean(img, axis=0)  

# find the channels which have the minimum average value
channel_select = np.argmin(mean_columns, axis=1)

# reshape the result just to be passed into take_along_axis
channel_select = np.expand_dims(channel_select, axis=(0, 2))

# take the selected channels, squeeze just removes an unnecessary axis
gray = np.take_along_axis(img, channel_select, axis=2).squeeze()
```

And here's the result from that operation:

[image: corrected]

A tidy way you can view this is a grayscale image in RGB has three identical channels, i.e. it holds redundant information. Some of your image columns are corrupted by some of the channels being scaled up in value, but the minimum value is invariant under this process unless *all* the channels are corrupted. So exploiting this invariant allows you to recover most of the data.

Comment: This is an incredible result. The math is clear as well as the `python processing`. THANK YOU. I've mistaken and used `windows snipping tool` to provide a piece of the actual `BMP` image, which why it was uploaded to stack as `JPEG`. It might be the cause of the mentioned failures. ALL THE BEST.

Comment: @OriDavid if you can save off an original image as PNG and update the OP, I'll update the answer too, accordingly! Would be interested to see what it looks like if JPEG isn't inherently part of the process :)

Comment: Updated to the `BMP` one (which I've downloaded from the challenge website), though I suspect stack saved it as `PNG`. Either way, the community may learn from this case, and acknowledge the effects of changing format :)

Comment: Is it acceptable for you to post the all code? Like the code results in first graph, second graph, ..., and result?

Answer (score 1):

"Given a pixel (252, 173, 28), as RGB format, I need to identify if it's colored or black & white." -Black will be near (0,0,0) and white (255,255,255) look to the [RGB Color Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space).
You can use the FFT approach to remove some kind of frequencies as you can see into  [this post](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Ebrayer/vision/fourier.html).

Comment: Thank you. I acknowledge the black & white values but what about between? ```(252, 173, 28)``` is gray. It has both high and low values.

Comment: In fact grey(colors) will have many values. You can learn more about Color Space and relationship with pixels values (R,G,B) here https://learnopencv.com/color-spaces-in-opencv-cpp-python/.

Answer (score 0):

A conversion to greyscale seems to be a reasonable start:

```
import cv2

# Load image as greyscale and save
im = cv2.imread('rainbow.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imwrite('result.png',im)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the division-normalization in OpenCV

---

- 1. Convert input to the gray-scale
- 2. Apply Gaussian-blur
- 3. Apply Division

---

```py
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Step 1: Convert input to the grayscale
    img = cv2.imread("kztMK.png")
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Step 2: Apply Gaussian Blur
    blr = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry, (95, 95), 0)

    # Step 3: Apply Division
    div = cv2.divide(gry, blr, scale=125)
```

Result:

[image]